# Why is the OR not working in a conditional statement?

Tags: conditionals, segments, advanced-conditionals

Running EE 3.5.15

I am trying to show content based on URL segment and the following is not working correctly:

```
 {if "{segment_2}" != "portfolio" || "{segment_2}" != "photos"}
  <p>Conditional content.</p>
 {/if}
```

If I use one of the conditionals by itself it works correctly, but when I introduce the OR into it, it fails.

I have tried the following:

```
{if "{segment_2}" != "portfolio" OR "{segment_2}" != "photos"}
```

and

```
{if segment_2 != "portfolio" || segment_2 != "photos"}
```

I have also tried it with single quotes.

Any suggestions on this elementary issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well here is the issue. You are trying to give OR condition for 2 strings. OR condition will return true if any one of the given statements are true.

If you want to execute the code when url_title not equal to "portfolio" neither equal to "photos" use this condition:

```
{if segment_2 != "portfolio" && segment_2 != "photos"}
    <p>Conditional content.</p>
{/if}
```

Or as a simle way:

```
{if ! "portfolio|photos" *= segment_2}
    I am here
{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks Mufi. While the logic at first does not make sense because technically you can't be on both pages at once, it does work and who am I to argue with success?

Answer (score 3):

You should try your code in below manner.

```
{if ! 'portfolio|photos' *= segment_2}
    <h1>Conditional content.</h1>
{/if}
```

You can also try in another way also.

```
{if segment_2 == 'portfolio' OR segment_2 == 'photos'}
{if:else}
    <h1>Conditional content.</h1>
{/if}
```

Comment: Harsh, thank you for the suggested solutions. The first one did not work, although I wish it had because it is tidy. The second option did work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 {if segment_2 != 'portfolio' OR segment_2 != 'photos'}
        <h1>Conditional content.</h1>
 {/if}
```

I've just tested, it works fine.

Comment: I tried it and it will not work for me. Thank  you though.